# Android : How to detect app killed from recent apps list?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, activity-lifecycle

So, I seen answers to this question in Stackoverflow, but I don't found final answer. So, I've following a problem: I've separated Thread to Socket. And I create and start this thread on Application onCreate method. And I need intercept this thread when application killed from recent apps list. If user press back button system will call to onDestroy, and this situation I can intercept socket thread. But, I can't intercept socket thread when user kill app from recent apps list.

Anybody have final answer how to solve this problem?

Comment: I need listen socket in background, if app not destroyed

Comment: Wait..if i remembered correctly, thread will automatically destroyed when the activity is destroyed..means your thread will be stop if the user kill from recent app list

Comment: Really? if app is killed from recent apps list and socket thread intercept, too?

Comment: As far as i know, it is why Google create a Service class. Async and Thread destroyed when the activity is destroyed, Service is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64366/discussion-between-mr-boyfox-and-blaze-tama).

Comment: ok, system destroy and recreate service if memory is low, what do you mean about this?